# JAVA: HashCode : Is it possible more than one elemets has same hashcode?

Tags: java, hashcode

I have read in a book that

"The value received from `hashcode()` is used as bucket number for storing elements."

My doubt is if the bucket contains more than one elements(with same `hashcode` value),How can differentiate the elements ?

OR

Is it possible more than one elemets has same `hashcode` ?

Comment: Buckets can contain more than one element. The container will use `equals()` to check if each of them is the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are two ways to handle the situation where two or more elements end up in the same "bucket" in a hash table:

- A bucket can be a linked list (or equivalent) and hold lots of elements.  This is how `HashMap` works ... though in Java 8, the linked list can be a binary tree.
- A bucket can have a bounded size, and then "overflow" into another one.

---

> My doubt is if the bucket contains more than one elements(with same hashcode value).  How can differentiate the elements ?

In Java, the `HashMap`, `Hashtable` and related classes, use the key's `equals` method to differentiate keys with the same hashcode. That's why we have the "hashcode / equals contract".  (Read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--).)

> Is it possible more than one elemets has same hashcode?

Yes it is possible.  Java's standard hash table classes cope with it.  See above.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple elements can have the same hashcode. In this case all the elements in that bucket will be checked using the `equals()` method to determine if one of them matches the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have more than one element with same hashcode cause count of hashcode is limited set. And you can differentiate the elements via `equals()` method.